# How can I optimize this query over 15000 records for Datawarehouse

Tags: query-optimization, data-warehouse

Can someone help me to optimize this query?

This is taking a lot of time to get done in TOAD:

```sql
select dim.comply_hotlist_sid --,DIM.HOTLISTID,dim.tin1,dim.* 
from EDW_WDS.D_T2_COMPLY_HOT_LIST dim 
where dim.COMPLY_HOTLIST_CURRENT_FLG = 'Y' 
and DIM.HOTLISTID in  
( 
   select distinct CMP.HOTLISTID 
   from MKT.D_CUSTOMER tp 
   join DW_ods.N_COMPLY_HOT_LIST cmp 
     on CMP.TIN1 = TP.SSN_TAX_ID 
   join  DW_DW.D_LOAN_VERSION_2 ln 
     on LN.LOAN_ACCT_NBR = TP.LOAN_ACCT_NBR 
   join DW_DW.AGG_LOAN_SS_MONTHLY mnt 
     on MNT.LOAN_SID= LN.LOAN_SID 
   where CMP.STATUSCODE = 'A' 
   and CMP.ISLASTLOAD = 'Y' 
   and TP.LOAN_ACCT_NBR is not null 
   and TP.SSN_TAX_ID <> ' ' 
   and TP.SSN_TAX_ID is not null )
```

Comment: How long is it taking now? What's the desired performance? What have you tried? What do you suspect is the bottleneck?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: I know there is problem with the indexes not created in the EDW_WDS.D_T2_COMPLY_HOT_LIST, I only hace read only permissions so is not like I can add the Index. I Canceled the query after 14 minutes running. That table has 15000 records so I guess it will take like forever

Comment: 15000 is trivial with indexes. Run the following command for each `tableName`: `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName`, and edit the results into your question.

Comment: I cleaned up your sql and improved your title. I'm not sure if this is Oracle but if it is please add that tag! please see the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting